# Previous User Controls stay active after changing ContenControl content

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contentcontrol

In my `WPF` application I have one main window and two User Controls and I use the following code to change in between my User Controls:

```
    private void SwitchControls(MyButton btnCurrent)
    {
        switch (btnCurrent.Name)
        {
            case "btnLine":
                {
                    winLine win = new winLine();
                    ccContent.Content = win;
                }
                break;
            case "btnHistory":
                {
                    winHistory win = new winHistory();
                    ccContent.Content = win;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

`ccContent` is my ContentControl inside my main window. `winLine` and `winHistory` are my two User Controls. In my `winLine` I have a timer that Ticks every 5 secs and whenever I switch to `winHistory` timer in previous User Control keeps ticking. I tried to do `ccContent.Content = null;` before switching User Controls, but it didn't help.

How do I disable or remove previous User Control and keep only an active one? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Check `Content` property before replacing it with something new.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. How can I clear the `Content`?

Comment: Probably the easiest solution might be to simply subscribe to [`Unloaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event in user control with timer and stop the timer there.

Answer (score 0):

Stop and dispose the timer before you reset the `Content` property. You could do this by trying to cast the value of the `Content` property to `winLine` using the `as` operator:

```
private void SwitchControls(MyButton btnCurrent)
{
    winLine current = ccContent.Content as winLine;
    if (current != null && current.Timer != null)
    {
        current.Timer.Stop();
        current.Timer.Dispose();
    }

    switch (btnCurrent.Name)
    {
        case "btnLine":
            {
                winLine win = new winLine();
                ccContent.Content = win;
            }
            break;
        case "btnHistory":
            {
                winHistory win = new winHistory();
                ccContent.Content = win;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```